# Passing key/value anonymous object as parameter

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-4.0

In mvc i can use construction like this

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.iEventSummary, new { @class = "test" })
```

I'm trying to reproduce this `new { @class = "test" }` as parameter but unsuccessfully

```
testFunction( new {key1="value1", key2="value2", key3="" })

public static string testFunction(dynamic dict)
{
    string ret = string.Empty;
    IDictionary<string, string> dictionary = dict;
    foreach (var item in dictionary)
    {
        ret += item.Key + item.Value;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

How does a method variable must be declared? 
If I want pass `new {key1="value1", key2="value2", key3="" }` as  parameter.

Comment: Look into [Tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx), available from from .NET 4 onwards these allow you to group objects.

Comment: You can remove "(dynamic)" from the title since it can be misleading, there's nothing dynamic about anonymous objects, there's only a compiler generated type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static string TestFunction(object obj)
{
    //To dictionary
    //var dict = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
    //                .ToDictionary(p=>p.Name,p=>p.GetValue(obj,null));

    //Directly ToString
    string result = String.Join(",", obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                                        .Select(p=>p.Name + ":" + p.GetValue(obj,null)));

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can convert anonymous object to IDictionary using RouteValueDictionary. Change your function to:

```
public static string TestFunction(object obj)
{
    var dict = new RouteValueDictionary(obj);
    var ret = "";
    foreach (var item in dict)
    {
        ret += item.Key + item.Value.ToString();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And you can use it:

```
TestFunction(new { key1="value1", key2="value2", key3="" });
```

Comment: yes, i can do this -but the problem is that i want to do this in one line without declaring anything just like in htmlhelper - testFunction( new {key1="value1", key2="value2", key3="" })

Comment: then move var dict = new RouteValueDictionary(obj); inside of function and make function argument type - object